# Since 本来 means both "originally" and "of course", how can I determine if 他本来是老师 means "he was originally a teacher" or "he is of course a teacher"?

Tags: meaning, word

> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%9C%AC%E6%9D%A5): 本来 (běn​lái​) original / originally / at first / it goes without saying / of course

I'm interested in the two adverb meanings of 本来, which my dictionary's definitions are:

1. （副）从前，先前。
2. （副）表示理所当然。

In some contexts, we can easily distinguish between these two meanings.  However, sometimes it's not so simple.

> 他**本来**是老师。

I get the impression this is ordinarily interpreted as meaning "he was originally a teacher", but I don't see why it cannot also be interpreted as meaning "he is of course a teacher" via the second adverb meaning above.

**Question**: Since 本来 means both "originally" and "of course", how can I determine if 他本来是老师 means "he was originally a teacher" or "he is of course a teacher"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meaning of "of course" is usually used in a structure of 本来+就. In your example without 就, I don't think 本来 can mean "originally".

A good explanation can be found [here](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22originally%22_with_%22benlai%22).

Answer (score 1):

- A: 他原本是做什麼的? B: 他本来(originally)是老师. This answer is a plain statement of fact - He originally was a teacher (it happens in the past, most likely not for now).
- A: 他看起來像是教書的. B: 他本来就(of course)是老师. This answer is affirming the assumed position of the object in the question, with a slight sense of ridicule - He is a teacher without saying (it implies now, at this moment of speaking).

Comment: It seems both interpretations are possible, depending on context.  Right?

Comment: I think it's uncommon to interpret 本来as "of course" without the 就, like what kyc pointed out

Comment: Please note the difference between the questions and the answers. In general, yes, it is depending on the context. See updates.